# unable to run oracle through command line in oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have successfully installed Oracle 11g Express Edition but when I click on "Run SQL Command Line" popup appears that says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application".

Can anyone please guide me with this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: seems to be like you need to reinstall the oracle 11g express edition again. might have not installed properly because the exe is not starting correctly. another thing is you might have a 64 bit machine and you might be using a 32 bit installer.

Comment: yes I reinstalled it again and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be like you need to **reinstall the oracle 11g express edition** again. might have not installed properly because the exe is not starting correctly. another thing is you might have a 64 bit machine and you might be using a 32 bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

to be answer:

**you should reinstall it.**

most probably it is not installed properly.